# I want to call a method from two different classes and I don't know how to

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently trying to return an integer within my database into a variable for me to compare to another integer but I keep getting errors, such as connections not opening. I've tried connecting the database to the other class, ineffective. It keeps telling me:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.'

```
class Database
{
    //connection
    public SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
    public Database()
    {
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();
    }

    public SqlCommand CreateCommand()
    {
        return sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    }

    public int compare()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        int ID = dr.GetInt32(0);
        return ID;
    }

    public void ExecuteSql(string sql)
    {
        var cmd = CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

public partial class FmLogin : Form
{
        Database database = new Database();
        public FmLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int holder = database.compare();
        if (holder > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"2",
            "Thank you for making an account!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just looking at your `compare()` function, your `cmd` has no instructions on what to query, and is not using a connection at all.

Comment: Also, don't leave your connection open like that.  When you query, you open, get the data, close.

Comment: Keeping an always-open connection to a database and sharing that connection manually in your code is a *famously* bad idea.  In any given method which needs to query the database, the code should create the connection/command/etc. and invoke the query all in as small a scope as necessary, disposing of the command/connection/etc. objects afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using your CreateCommand() method from the compare() method.

I'd suggest you do all in the Compare() method like this:

```
public int Compare()
{
    int ID;
    SqlCommand cmd = CreateCommand();        
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id FROM mytable" // adapt your statement here
    using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        dr.Read();
        ID = dr.GetInt32(0);
    }
    return ID;
}
```

I also put a using around the `SqlDataReader` to dispose it after it's not needed anymore. Otherwise you cannot use the connection for other commands

Comment: Why do you suggest that OP still shouldn’t use their own `CreateCommand()` method? BUT instead `CreateCommand` from the `sqlConnection`.

Comment: @Rand you're right. I've changed my answer to use the already created factory method for the command.